# Flutter: how to logout of facebook and get the login dialog

Tags: facebook, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am authentication with Facebook from my flutter app. This is working , however , the login dialog only shows the first time .

After I logoff I don't get the login prompt again.. The only method to see the login dialog again is go  the FB and logoff

Can please let me know I can logoff of facebook from my flutter app and show the login dialog..

Google auth work great.. I see the login dialog

Logoff code

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    randstadUserProfile = null;
    firebaseUser = null;
  }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issues . will please help me?

Comment: hey, did you find the solution?

Comment: anyone got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible

Quote from official doc

> The Android and iOS SDKs don't currently support re-authentication.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/re-authentication

Answer (score -2):

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:pixeltech/Body/Onboard/screens/entry_screen.dart';

class NotificationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationPageState createState() => _NotificationPageState();
}

class _NotificationPageState extends State<NotificationPage> {



  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FacebookLogin facebookLogIn = FacebookLogin();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:FlatButton(onPressed: (){
          signOutGoogle();
          logoutFacebook();
        }, child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app))
      )
    );
  }



  ///google signout
  void signOutGoogle() async{
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {return EntryScreen();},),);
    print("Sign Out");
  }
  //facebook logout
  void logoutFacebook() async{
  await facebookLogIn.logOut();
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {return EntryScreen();},),);
  print("User Sign Out");
}
}
```